# why URL giving response when executed separately but not in forkJoin?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, fork-join

My url is giving proper result when executed in Postman app but when I bundle 100 such urls in forkjoin, I'm getting response for some url and others are returning empty array,  I have cross checked all 100 IDs and all of them has data in them. What can be the issue? [image: Image of forkjoin respo.]

Response in postman :
[image]

JS CODE AS FOLLOWS

I'm creating an array of all requests like this :

```
 let allprocall  = []
 allprocall.push(this.http.get(this.api.APIURL+'get_milestones/'+this.user.username  + '/'+ this.user.password + '/'+ this.listproj[i].pid))
```

and then executing using forkJoin :

```
forkJoin(allprocall).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Please also include some code.

Comment: added code in description

Comment: If you look at the requests and responses in your browser's developer tools, you should spot the error.